# Tooltip buttons not working as expected/ Tooltip Closing when button is clicked

Tags: angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I have a button which opens ngbTooltip on click. Inside ngbTooltip I have a button which should console log a string.
Clicking on the button inside the tooltip only closes the tooltip but no string is logged in the console.

```
<button 
[ngbTooltip]="popContent" 
placement="right" 
triggers="click"> Xyz </button>

<ng-template #popContent><div>
 <button (click)="download()">abc</button>
</div></ng-template>

download(){
 console.log('Clicked');
}
```

I have tried using [autoClose]="'outside'" but it did not help. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: issue not reproducible in [`stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dthe6s?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-basic.html,src%2Fapp%2Ftooltip-basic.ts)

Comment: if it helps I am using version 13 of ng-bootstrap @NarenMurali
e.preventDefault() did the trick for me!! stupidity :)

Comment: it happens to us all :) glad its fixed